# PHP regex removes segment before and including period

Tags: php, regex

I have a chunk of PHP code that parses email addresses out of a large string that contains a jumble of email addresses:

```
$pattern = '/[a-z0-9_\-\+]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,3})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i';
preg_match_all($pattern, $emailBatch, $matches);
```

This works perfectly except that any email address that contains a period before the `@` gets truncated.

Example: `jim.dandy@foo.com` becomes `dandy@foo.com`

How can I modify the regex to allow/accept periods (and any other legal character for email addresses) in the address?

Comment: can you provide sample input?

Comment: `^(?:[\w\!\#\$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`\{\|\}\~]+\.)*[\w\!\#\$\%\&\'\*\+\-\/\=\?\^\`\{\|\}\~]+@(?:(?:(?:[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-](?!\.)){0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]?\.)+[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9\-](?!$)){0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9]?)|(?:\[(?:(?:[01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(?:[01]?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\]))$` ... simple, or, you know, [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.validation.php) ... probably best not to RYO email validation RegEx, odds are it'll not match RFC 2822 spec.

Comment: This RegEx will also fail on a lot of the new TLDs that have been released, like `.online`

Comment: How is your emails string delimited?  Probably better to split on that versus trying to dissect email addresses.  Please update your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first group of the pattern you need to add a dot:

```
$pattern = '/[a-z0-9_\-\+\.]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,3})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i';
preg_match_all($pattern, $emailBatch, $matches);
```

Because it is not specified in the first group it catches only the second part (that is right before `@` sign).

Comment: this pattern in this answer will _technically_ miss some valid emails, but I can suggest a more brief/condensed version of the pattern that is free from unnecessary escaping: `~[\w.+-]+@[a-z\d-]+\.([a-z]{2,3})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?~i`